# User is not authenticated in django?

Tags: django, authentication

I am using Django Version:  3.0.2. Student registration is working and user is saving to database successfully. The problem is after login it is showing User but after redirect to other page it is showing none. Please any one solve my problem?

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, auth

def studentregistration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            confirmpassword = form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            if password == confirmpassword:
                if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                    messages.error(request,'user already exists please login')
                    return render(request, 'login.html')
                elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(request, 'email already registered please login')
                    return render(request, 'login.html')
                else:
                    user=User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
                    user.save()
                    messages.success(request, "Successfully registered, Please login")
                    return render(request, 'login.html')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'password and confirmation password do not match')
                return render(request, 'studentregistration.html')
                #return HttpResponseRedirect('studentregistration.html')
    else:
        form = StudentRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'studentregistration.html', {'form': form})


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('user_name', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('exam_pattern')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'invalid credentials')
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
      
        return render(request,'login.html')
```

Here, i am autheticated user, but it is showing user in render_questions is none.

```
def render_questions(request):
    
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
       return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        global exam_session
        exam_session = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
        
        questions = Questions.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'report.html', {'ques': questions})


After log in it is showing user: user is gopi14
[2020-11-03 06:18:19 +0000] [31827] [DEBUG] GET /exam_pattern
[2020-11-03 06:18:21 +0000] [31827] [DEBUG] POST /report
after redirect to report it is showing none

user in render_questions is
```

Comment: use [**`@login_required(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator

Comment: `is_authenticated` instead of `authenticated`

Comment: @Daniel Still i am not getting. After log in it is showing user: user is gopi14
[2020-11-03 06:18:19 +0000] [31827] [DEBUG] GET /exam_pattern
[2020-11-03 06:18:21 +0000] [31827] [DEBUG] POST /report
 after redirect to report it is showing none:  user in render_questions is